# Run maven goal with special symbols in arguments on Linux

Tags: bash, maven, special-characters, bamboo

We have continuous integration tool Bamboo.
There I can define a maven task with actual command.
Command are ran on a Linux machine.
I need to provide a password for some plugin in build, but password contains special symbols. i.e. 123'123

Maven command looks like

```
mvn clean install -Dsome.property.password=${bamboo.some_psw}
```

1. `mvn clean install -Dsome.property.password=123'123`
   This fails with message that No goals have been specified for this build. Ok I need to escape special symbols.
2. `mvn clean install -Dsome.property.password="123'123"`Now it is OK for maven to run the gole. But there is custom plugin in build with XML config with a placeholder like

`<someTag user="SOME_USER" password="${some.property.password}"/>`

and it fails here with XML parsing with message "Element type "someTag" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"." with column number starting at ${some.property.password}. So looks like that quote was passed both with value, and XML could not be parsed..

3. Tried to use single quotes:

`mvn clean install -Dsome.property.password='123'\''123'`

Same error again arguing that 'No goals have been specified for this build'

Same if `mvn clean install -Dsome.property.password=123\'123`

Everything works OK if password is without special symbols i.e.

`mvn clean install -Dsome.property.password=somepass`

By the way on local Windows machine everything works fine with

`mvn clean install -Dsome.property.password="123'123"`

Any idea how to pass here a value in arguments with special symbols when calling maven?

Comment: Question about those things you tried and the results you got - Did you try from the shell directly (without Bamboo) or did you made Bamboo execute them? Asking as both `mvn clean -Dsome.property.password="123'123"` and `mvn clean -Dsome.property.password=123\'123` work just fine in bash.

Comment: No I didn't as have no access to and build agent is picked up by BAMBOO tool..Tried to execute ECHO on Linux machine I had, and it was fine too..

Comment: So what you did is you pleased those commands in some place where Bamboo picks them up from and execute them. You have no access to the machine to test the commands on the shell directly.  Am I understanding correctly what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple layers here and each if them may do (or may need to but not do) some escaping or value parsing:

- given maven plugin
- maven itself
- the shell (bash, sh, ...)
- bamboo logic that calls Maven
- bamboo properties

It's likley that what one layer does conflicts with what the next one expects. But it is next to impossible without debugging to tell what exactly the isuse is. For sure both of those:

- `mvn clean -Dsome.property.password="123'123"`
- `mvn clean -Dsome.property.password=123\'123`

work just fine when executed directly in bash. However it may be that Bamboo uses different shell, or it does something with the variable. You may try to use something like [echo-maven-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/echo-maven-plugin) to print what exactly bamboo passes:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>debug</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <configuration>
              <message>${some.property.password}</message>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

May be that will give you a hint what is wrong with the final value (if anything at all).

There is also an option (although unlikely) that the plugin you are configuring with `< someTag ...` does not read/parse configuration properly.

Comment: Thank you Milen for suggestion to log properties with this plugin, it gave very interesting results. When using double quotes in command "123'123" then it prints "123'123, when passing '123123' it prints '123123'

Comment: Interesting. Did you figure out what makes the closing quote to disappear? Have you tried by simply escaping the single quote like `123\'123`  ?

Comment: Hi MIlen, yes I tried and maven fails with  'No goals have been specified for this build' :) I have created an issue for Bamboo team.. Will update here afterwards..